# Deleting free trial of azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, subscription, cancellation

I am trying to delete a free trial of AzureAD but there are two requisites that I am unable to get past these are

- Delete all licence-based subscriptions
- Delete all azure-subscriptions

[image: Screenshot or pre-requisites]

When you click on the first option this states there are no subscriptions to delete? 
If you try the second option and navigate to the trial there is no cancel option as this trials status is set to disabled?

Anyone know how to proceed so I can get this test AzureAD account gone?

Comment: I've had this problem trying to delete the active directory. I have no subscriptions and if I try to delete service principals using the powershell I get this is a microsoft internal Id error. I switched to a local global account and removed my account and just left if. Otherwise you need to raise a ticket with them to delete your card.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a directory in Azure Active Directory, you need to meet all the checks.

Azure trial subscription will be canceled automatically after the trial. But you cannot delete the subscription yourself. You will need to wait 90 days before permanently deleting your data in case that you need to access it again.

Here is the reply from MicrosoftDocs.

> You can't delete an Azure subscription directly. As the article
>   states, all an account admin needs to do is Cancel subscription.
>   Billing stops at that point and all Azure services get disabled, but a
>   final invoice isn’t created until the end of the current billing
>   period. 90 days after you cancel the subscription, Azure automatically
>   permanently deletes the subscription and all data.

Reference:

[Can not delete subscription](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33173)

[Add an option to delete disabled subscriptions](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/6436523-add-an-option-to-delete-disabled-subscriptions-it)